# Solving $key=(\sum_{K=0}^n\frac{1}{a^K})\mod m$ with High limits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I was solving this equation:-
$$key=(\sum_{K=0}^n\frac{1}{a^K})\mod m$$

#### Given

$$ 1,000,000,000 < a, n, m \; < 5,000,000,000 $$
$$ a, m \; are \;coprime $$

I solved it bruteforcely but it won't work in the given constrains so I need a faster algorithm or is there is something I can notice to make the formula easier to solve ?